# Vertical scroll div different speed

Tags: jquery, performance, scroll, layer

I want to create a page with different layers (different z-index i guess) and each layer has a different speed on scroll. I've been trying to use the parallax effect but it's not exactly what I need because it's base on background-images of div. And those divs are "cutted" by the next div and so on... What I need it's something simpler.

I was thinking in one big div to be a background - in this one some images at different heigh. this will allow to show one image and when i'm scrolling down to see the others.
2 divs at different level (z-index) with a scroll speed different between them and from the 1st (big) div.

However I'm not achieving it! Am I thinking right? Is this possible?

Thanks,

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thinks parallax would be your solution even if you have crossed this choice.

Have you seen this tutorial ?

http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/create-a-funky-parallax-background-effect-using-jquery/

Maybe it's more something like this that you want ?

Comment: Yes, I found that one as well. But as I said I thought that a non-parallax could be the solution. That tutorial it's horizontal - I'm ok with that, but do you think that I can scroll with browser if I put vertically?

Comment: Yeah scrollTo can be vertical : http://www.queness.com/resources/html/scroll/vertical.html

And you ca use this: http://api.jquery.com/scroll/
To detect when the browser is scrolled 

A mix of all that should give you a solution

Comment: Greg thanks. I think that this can help me. But... maybe I didn't explain properly. This scroll that I mentioned is in the browser window. Like in http://www.nikebetterworld.com/ where you can scroll through the right menu or in browser...

Comment: Yeah use the scroll event to scrollTo you different div to a different speed, that should work :) . Mark as accepted if it's working

Comment: Thanks Greg. I'd like to mark as useful but I don't have enough "reputation". I'm not marking it as an answer because I need to see if it really works this way.

Comment: Not exactly Greg. Your reply helped me to understand some issues right. But there was a problem in that example. It was only about scrolling when you press some button but I need to do it when I scroll the page and with the mouse. I already have this code:

Comment: $(window).scroll(function () {
 $("#logo").animate({ "top": "+=50px" }, 1000);
 $("#logo2").animate({ "top": "+=100px"}, 1000);
 });   but there are some problems still. 1 just scroll down. 2 when I scroll through browser the elements should move faster. 3 If I scroll more than once this don't work properly. Any help?